# Cambiar de Font y background dependiendo del rango del valor en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenos días comunidad de programadores, tengo un dilema el cual me he checado y analizado pero pues obviamente mi cabeza ya no da para más.

Tengo varios input el cual si pongo un valor dentro de n rango este cambia el font-weight y font-size y hasta ahí todo me sale de maravilla, el detalle es que cuando esos valores que meten en el input son guardados en la bd y luego mostrados con un echo en el value pues ya no me reconoce dichos cambios, lo que quiero saber saber es como puedo hacerle para que me respete los mismos cambios como al principio.

Les muestro el código:

```
<tr>
    <td  align="center">GLUCOSA</td>
    <td  align="center"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="glucosa" id="glucosa" onkeyup="glu(this)" style="text-align: center;" onkeypress="return numeros(event)" value="<?php echo $resul2["glucosa"]; ?>"/></td>                                 
    <td  align="center">mg./dl.</td>
    <td  align="center">70 - 110</td>
</tr>
```

y en JavaScript tengo lo siguiente:

```
function glu(elemento){
  if ($(elemento).val() < 70 | $(elemento).val() > 110 ) {
    $(elemento).css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(elemento).css("font-size", "15px");
  }
  else{
    $(elemento).css("font-weight", "");
    $(elemento).css("font-size", "15px");
  }
}
```

**Como les comento quiero que en el mismo input donde meto los valores y si se pasa del rango que tengo asignado este cambie una vez los datos estén guardados en la base de datos y mostrados con php.
Al igual otro favor deria como hacerle para que el 70 - 110 cambie de color dependiendo si se pasa del valor o no.

Saludos y gracias.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al traer los datos de la bd nunca entras al evento keyup, por lo tanto debes ejecutarlo una vez que ya se cargó el sitio.

Por otra parte, si este input lo tienes varias veces debes quitarle el id, ya que deben ser únicos

```
// Agrega una clase al input
<input class="form-control glu-selector" type="text" name="glucosa" id="glucosa" onkeyup="glu(this)" style="text-align: center;" onkeypress="return numeros(event)" value="<?php echo $resul2["glucosa"]; ?>"/>


// En tu script, agrega un iniciador
$(() => {
    $('.glu-selector').each(function () {
        let item = $(this);
        if (item.val() < 70 || item.val() > 110 ) {
            item.css("font-weight", "bold");
            item.css("font-size", "15px");
       }
       else {
            item.css("font-weight", "");
            item.css("font-size", "15px");
       }
    });
})
```

Comment: Buenas tardes estimado Jonathan Orta, ya lo hice como me indicaste pero sigue sin funcionarme, de hecho ahora ya no me reconoce lo primero que hacia q es si ingreso un valor que sobrepase los valores cambia el estilo, que crees que estoy haciendo mal??